# Send jsonArray to method MVC controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have the following ajax script

```
$(function () {
                $("#btnConfirmParticipants").click(function () {
                    var jsonArray = [];
                    $(".form-horizontal").each(function () {
                        jsonArray.push({ Name: ($(this).find("#Name").val()), Surname: ($(this).find("#Surname").val()), BirthDate: ($(this).find("#BirthDate").val()) });
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/ClientReservations/AddParticipants",
                        data: JSON.stringify(jsonArray),
                        dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (response) {

                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

This script is responsible for executing method in controller with List as parameter

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles ="Klient")]
        public ActionResult AddParticipants(IList<Participant> participants)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Model **Participant** looks like this

```
public class Participant
    {

        public Participant()
        {
            this.Reservation_House_Participant = new HashSet<Reservation_House_Participant>();
        }

        [Display(Name ="Id:")]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Imię:")]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(3),MaxLength(15)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Nazwisko:")]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(3),MaxLength(15)]
        public string Surname  { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Data urodzenia:")]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode =true)]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

When I click button to execute ajax script it redirects me to controller method and in debbuger I see that parameter **IList participants** is null? What could be the reason?

Comment: Try to use a simple `string[]` and then debug it

Comment: @Uphar you might be crazy. You can't put `var` over there.

Comment: string[] the same result

Comment: Maybe I shoud import some json library using nuGet?

Comment: @Contador6 give me a second, I'm trying to debug it

Comment: Try using List or IEnumerable

Comment: I have checked this option.

Comment: Have you checked that ‍‍`jsonArray` is full in view?

Comment: How can I check this, debugger surely will not show me this.

Comment: The code you have shown should work fine, but try `data: JSON.stringify({ participants: jsonArray }),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it didn't helped, the server method should receive a model

Comment: @LabLab, What? Its not your question! And it IS receiving a model - a collection of `Participant`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yeap, but I debugged that to find a solution and tried that way which you have described in your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your jQuery, you need to set the `contentType`, not the `dataType` property:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ClientReservations/AddParticipants",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonArray),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //<-- this line
    success: function (response) {

    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```